# How do I spell a word that sounds like "reh-par-tay" and often used with "witty"?

Tags: orthography, loanwords

Clever conversation, aka "witty [reh-par-tay]" ... can't for the life of me remember how to spell that loan word, though I use it in spoken English from time to time.

I am pretty sure it's not *repertoire*.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=rehpartay "Showing results for ***repartee***" … "Noun: Conversation or speech characterized by quick, witty comments." Right there at the top.

Comment: Just to help you remember...: There was a young man named McGee - who took a sojourn in Paree - When they asked "Parlay Vous?" - he replied "Same to you!" - a fine bit a fast repartee.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That word would be *repartee.*  (Since it's French, I've sometimes seen it spelled with an accented e, *repartée*, even though it's not necessarily supposed to have one.)

[repartee at dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/repartee)

Comment: Look at the pronunciation there:  Like the French original "repartie".

Comment: The word "repartée" does not exist in French. @GEdgar: the French original is "répartie".